# .Net Core RabbitMQ/Masstransit one consumer per configurable number of threads in same app

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I can create a workerservices that create and configure a n number of RabbitMQ consumer, each one in is own thread for in-app load balancing.

I am new to Masstransit and I don not know how to configure the way I want. I found this code to consume message type queues in configureservices:

```
   // MassTransit-RabbitMQ Configuration
        services.AddMassTransit(config => {

            config.AddConsumer<BasketCheckoutConsumer>();

            config.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) => {
                cfg.Host(Configuration["EventBusSettings:HostAddress"]);
                cfg.UseHealthCheck(ctx);

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(EventBusConstants.BasketCheckoutQueue, c => {
                    c.ConfigureConsumer<BasketCheckoutConsumer>(ctx);
                });
            });
        });
        services.AddMassTransitHostedService();

        // General Configuration
        services.AddScoped<BasketCheckoutConsumer>();
```

The question is, if I run a loop from 0 to n-1 running this line `services.AddScoped<BasketCheckoutConsumer>();`

will this crate n number of consumers? this is, consumers taking message from the same queue.

Am I in good direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consumers in MassTransit aren't using threads continuously. Consumers are also instantiated in a scope of a single message handling, so talking about threads makes no sense when it comes to the number of consumer instances.

MassTransit is fully asynchronous in terms of IO, and it will instantiate multiple instances of the same consumers to handle the load. You can specify how many concurrent consumers you want for a given receive endpoint by setting `ConcurtrentMessageLimit` in your configuration as it's [described in the docs](http://masstransit-project.com/releases/v7.1.6.html#prefetchcount-and-concurrentmessagelimit). Remember also to [adjust the prefetch count](http://masstransit-project.com/usage/transports/rabbitmq.html#guidance), so you actually get the concurrency level you want.

Comment: Setting ConcurrentMessageLimit on the receive endpoint is preferable to adding UseConcurrencyLimit.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPatterson, I will update the answer

Comment: @ChrisPatterson btw the docs say "The ConcurrentMessageLimit is only passed to transports that support it (currently, Azure Service Bus)"

Comment: Yeah, I need to update the documentation to [match the release notes](https://masstransit-project.com/releases/v7.1.6.html#prefetchcount-and-concurrentmessagelimit).

Comment: I read a little more and found that what I need the way to configure a "competing consumer pattern" with a single consumer class. What I did not find was a single example of how configure it in startup class, can you provide an example?

Comment: You get competing consumers out of the box in one process if you set the concurrency level higher than one. By default, you get parallel consumers already without doing anything. If you spin up more than one instance of your service, you get competing consumers across processes. Again, there's nothing to do, it just works out of the box.